# How to write Fractional Quantum Hall States with Symmetric Polynomials?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, solid-state-physics, quantum-hall-effect, chern-simons-theory

Is there a link between Fractional Quantum Hall States and Symmetric Polynomials.  In papers of Xiao Gang Wen [[1](http://arxiv.org/abs/1507.04673v2)], [[2](http://arxiv.org/abs/0801.3291)] work out a few examples:

- $ \Phi_{1/2} = \prod_{i < j} (z_i - z_j)^2$ is the [1/2 Laughlin State](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laughlin_wavefunction) and similarly $\Phi_{1/4} = \prod_{i < j} (z_i - z_j)^4$
- the rest of the paper **[2]** searches for arithmetic conditions on the exponent to get more polynomials

The more recent paper **[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BYXFj.png)** writes down an explicit state:

$$ \prod_{I; i < j} (z^I_i - z^I_j)^{K_{II}} \times \prod_{i; I < J} (z_i^I - z_i^J)^{K_{IJ}} \times e^{- \frac{1}{4}\sum_{i,I} |z_i^I|^2}$$

this time with the Gaussian.  Apologies if the letters are getting too small... is corresonds to Chern Simons theory with $\mathcal{L} = \frac{K_{IJ}}{4\pi} a_{I \mu} \partial_\nu a_{J \lambda} \epsilon^{\mu \nu \lambda}$.  This is part of Wen's "new mathematical language"

I would like to understand better how to write down these Abelian $U(1)$ Chern-Simons states, and how they relate to Wen's other approaches, in particular:

- symmetric polynomials
- pattern of zeros

There are numerous other references which I haven't had time to parse, written in the same neo-classical style.

[image]

Comment: What is your actual question? The proposed wavefunction corresponding to a generic U(1) Chern-Simons theory is already written down...

Comment: @MengCheng do these symmetric functions change in the same way as Anyons supposedly do?  do they exhibit braiding?

Comment: I found this paper [[3](http://arxiv.org/abs/1203.3268)] and this [question](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/29137/the-bijective-correspondence-between-a-symmetric-polynomial-and-edge-excitation?rq=1).

Comment: @MengCheng XGW says in various places is his own theory is incomplete in regards to computing fractional statistics for Abelian anyons

Comment: See also 'Jack Polynomials' https://arxiv.org/abs/0707.3637.